# C++ Finding the average of the numbers in an array

Tags: c++, arrays, average

```
for( k = 0; k < n; k++ )
{
   total += total + temps[k];
}

avgTemp = total / n;
```

`temps` is my array that contains `n` elements. `avgTemp` stores the average of all the values in `temps`. k is just some integer to make my loop work. k, n, and total are already declared appropriately somewhere above. `total` keeps track of the total of the elements in the array.

My exercise thing is telling me this is wrong. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `double avgTemp = std::accumulate(temps,temps+n,0.0) / n;` assuming `temps` is a bunch of temperatures stored as floating point values.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This

```
for( k = 0; k < n; k++ )
{
    /// here's the error.
    /// You assign the new value to total as (total = total + total + temps[k])
    total += total + temps[k];
}

avgTemp = total / n;
```

should be

```
for( k = 0; k < n; k++ ) { total += temps[k]; }

avgTemp = total / n;
```

or

```
for( k = 0; k < n; k++ ) { total = total + temps[k]; }

avgTemp = total / n;
```

Using the iterative summation would be even better. It allows to avoid the round-off errors.

```
avgTemp = temps[0];

for(k = 1 ; k < n ; k++) { total = (temps[k] + (double)(k-1) * total)/ (double)k; }
```

bames53 also gives a nice STL-based code in the comment.

Answer (score 2):

First, `total += temps[k]`

+= Means `total = total + temps[k]` already

And By the way,
Is total declared as float or double? Otherwise you are doing a integer Division.

Answer (score 2):

Your code is adding "total" to itself on every iteration, which is not what you want.  You need to change:

```
total += total + temps[k];
```

to

```
total += temps[k];
```

Answer (score 1):

When getting the sum of the numbers, you are adding the total to itself and then adding the next element.

```
total += total + temps[k];
```

should be:

```
total += temps[k];
```

Answer (score 0):

As is mentioned in [bames53's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10825557/c-finding-the-average-of-the-numbers-in-an-array#comment14092426_10825557) [`accumulate`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/accumulate) is really your best bet for solving this. Given `n` which is the size of the container and `it` which is either a pointer or iterator to the first element of the container, you can do this for arrays, dynamically allocated arrays, or vectors:

```
const auto avgTemp = accumulate(it, next(it, n), typename iterator_traits<remove_const_t<decltype(foo)>>::value_type{}) / n;
```

[<kbd>Live Example</kbd>](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e27646641b3147c1)